# Query part of string or text

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Using Rails and MySQL. Not sure if this has been asked, but couldn't find it.

I have the following records:

```
1. I love Rails
2. I love Django
3. I code using Ruby on Rails
```

====

(1) Search: "i love"

Results: "**I love** Rails", "**I love** Django"

====

(2) Search: "love"

Results: "I **love** Rails", "I **love** Django"

====

(3) Search: "ails"

Results: "I love Rails", "I code using Ruby on Rails"

====

(4) Search: "code Ruby"

Results: "I code using Ruby on Rails"

====

My code is:

```
term = "%#{params[:term]}%"
shops = Shop.where("name LIKE ?", term)
```

It only works on Search (1) and (2). How can I code to achieve results when doing search (3) and (4) too?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

I need to wrap each word in the search phrase with `%string%`.

====

Search (1): "i love"

Query: `SELECT * from t WHERE name LIKE "%i% %love%";`

Results: "I love Rails", "I love Django"

====

Search (2): "love"

Query: `SELECT * from t WHERE name LIKE "%love%";`

Results: "I love Rails", "I love Django"

====

Search (3): "ails"

Query: `SELECT * from t WHERE name LIKE "%ails%";`

Results: "I love Rails", "I code using Ruby on Rails"

====

Search (4): "code Ruby"

Query: `SELECT * from t WHERE name LIKE "%code% %Ruby%";`

Results: "I code using Ruby on Rails"

====

My Ruby code should be:

```
term = "#{params[:term]}"
f_term = term.gsub /\b/, '%'
shops = Shop.where("name LIKE ?", f_term)
```

You can test this at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d63f5/4

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need wildcards in there for this (in raw SQL)

```
LIKE '%ails'
```

or more generally:

```
LIKE '%substring%'
```

Comment: You should add a link to the singnifications of the %, _ and all other usefull caracters in SQL

Comment: I already used the `%substring%`. Please see additional search 4 added.